# How to change back ownership?

Tags: sudo, ownership

I change owner of some root files and folders like /etc/sudoers to www-data by mistake! And now I can't use "sudo" at all!
How can I change them back to my user?
It a ubuntu 18.04 server and I can olny access it via ssh.

Comment: In most cases it's impossible practically.

Comment: Thanks I can change chmod somehow but my problem is ownership!

Comment: This is almost same. And it depends on what commands you exactly ran.

Comment: sorry I can't boot to recovery

Comment: I add the line but nothing changed. I think becuase the file ownership is wrong